# Explode Task Time

Tags: php, explode

I one of my csv imports to the DB has a field value that looks like this '24h 30m'

How do i explode this to separate the two sets of numbers? Here's what i have so far

```
$tasktime  = "24h 30m";
$pieces = explode("h ", $tasktime);
echo $pieces[0]; // want this to echo 24
echo $pieces[1]; // want this to echo 30
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trivially easy ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wYtdKK))

```
$pieces = array_map('intval', explode(' ', "24h 30m"));
```

This will split the string by the space and then get the integer value from each of the two elements.

Further reference:

- [`explode` — Split a string by string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [`array_map` — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays](http://php.net/array_map)
- [`intval` — Get the integer value of a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)
- [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Comment: His comments seem to suggest he wants to cut off the letters? +1 anyway

Comment: @IsaacFife there wont be any letters in my solution after intval was applied

Comment: Ah, nice. I just started with php this week. I should probably just keep my mouth shut. ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
$tasktime  = "24h 30m";
$pieces = explode("h ", $tasktime);
$pieces[1] = rtrim($pieces[1], "m");
echo $pieces[0]; // want this to echo 24
echo $pieces[1]; // want this to echo 30
```

I actually don't know php but this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Thanks!

```
$tasktime  = "24h 30m";
$pieces = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $tasktime));
```

Answer (score 0):

If its always that format you could do this to get a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object.

```
$tasktime  = "24h 30m";    
$interval = new DateInterval('PT' . strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', $tasktime)));

print_r($interval);
```

Outputs

```
DateInterval Object
    (
        [y] => 0
        [m] => 0
        [d] => 0
        [h] => 24
        [i] => 30
        [s] => 0
        [invert] => 0
        [days] =>
    )
```

Comment: getting an error on DateInterval Object line

Comment: Sorry, thats just the output of the print_r, to show that its splitting it up correctly. You can get the hours with $interval->h and the minutes with $interval->i, or use it to do operations on DateTime objects. If you just want the values, one of the examples below is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might write it as a regex:

```
$tasktime = "24h 30m";
preg_match('/(\d+)h (\d+)m/', $tasktime, $pieces);
echo $pieces[1]; // echoes 24
echo $pieces[2]; // echoes 30
```